# QML drag from drawer to another item, how do I keep dragging continuous when drawer closes

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

My goal is to drag a copy of an `item` from the `drawer` and drop it on another `item`. When I press and hold on the `item`, I create a new `Rectangle` and reparent it to the new `parent` and set it as a `drag.target`
I would like to `close()` the `drawer` when I cross the boundary of the `drawer`.
My problem is that I am losing control over the dragged `item`. How can I keep dragging the `item` even if `drawer.close()` was called.
Here's a working example:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 600
    height: 600
    visible: true
    Item{
        id: root

        Drawer{
            id:drawer
            width: 0.5 * parent.width
            height: parent.height
            edge: Qt.RightEdge

            Rectangle {
                id: item
                border.width: 2
                x: 100
                y: 100
                width: 100
                height: 100


                MouseArea {
                    id: mouseArea
                    anchors.fill: parent

                    onPressAndHold: {
                        var newItem = createShadow(item)
                        newItem.parent = root
                        drag.target = newItem

                    }
                    onMouseXChanged: {
                        //hard coding the cursor crossing the drawer boundary
                        var point = mapToItem(root, mouseX, mouseY)
                        if (point.x < 300)
                            drawer.close()
                    }

                    onReleased: {
                        drag.target.Drag.drop()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        DropArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onDropped: {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }

    function createShadow(itm) {
        //assuming we are fetching geometry from itm
        var component = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.4; Rectangle{x:400;y:100;width:100;height:100;opacity:0.2;color:"black"}',root, "asdf");

        return component
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also reparent the `MouseArea` during the drag so that you keep receiving the `onMouseXChanged` events:

```
onPressAndHold: {
    var newItem = createShadow(item)
    newItem.parent = root
    drag.target = newItem
    parent = root
}
// ...
onReleased: {
    drag.target.Drag.drop()
    parent = item
}
```